# Python regex: Finding input not matching a specific (variable-defined) length

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing regular expressions in Python, but I keep getting this problem:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.
```

My regular expression:

```
searchResults = (re.findall("[0-9]{"+re.escape(columns)"}",content))
```

My variable columns is the length of the first element of a set (len(..)) of another regular expression. 
When I'm using a normal number it just works. 
When I try print(columns), I also see a normal number.

Thanks for your help!

Sample of content:

```
111111111111
100111011101
180101020111
1001010000112
101610170051
150100111001
101100111101
100010000111
100000801111
100081010111
111111111111
```

Sample for columns: 12

As the result I'm trying to get this line (which does not have 12 numbers): 1001010000112

Comment: Can you give us some sample patterns of your input string

Comment: re.escape takes *strings* as parameter, not an integer. Convert it with str(columns) first, and get rid of the re.escape, you don't need it for this.

Comment: Editing a question to replace it with a completely different question _after you already have answers_ is generally not considered kosher.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I just updated my post with a sample.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to explain my question but it seems that it was not clear. I'm sorry for this. I'll keep your reaction in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter for strings of not matching a specific length, the following will do the trick:

```
re.findall('(^[0-9]{0,%d}$|[0-9]{%d}[0-9])' % (columns, columns), s)
```

Comment: I'm trying to create a regular expressions which gives me the elements which don't iterate as much as the integer.
Columns is for example 7. Then I want to get all the elements which don't have 7 numbers.

Comment: This answer has been edited to address your intended, as opposed to initial, question.